# Configure python model in xampp

Tags: python

I installed `mod_python`, I try to run python script like:

```
from mod_python import apache
```

It show me the error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#3>", line 1, in <module>
    from mod_python import apache
  File "D:\Python27\lib\mod_python\apache.py", line 55, in <module>
    import _apache
ImportError: No module named _apache
```

I don't know why?

My enviroment:
Windows XP, Python 2.7.2

Comment: How did you install it and what are you trying to actually do?

Answer (score 0):

Its probably that the script location is not added to your path.

try:

```
import sys
sys.path
sys.path.append('/path/to/the/mod_python.py')
```

If this doesn't work, it was probably not installed correctly.

If you want to add it to your system path permanently so you don't have to use the code above every time check out this SO [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3701646/how-to-add-to-the-pythonpath-in-windows-7).

Answer (score 0):

If you don't get any help here, try the mod_python mailing list:

http://www.modpython.org/live/mod_python-2.7.8/doc-html/installation.html